# Download Shared Public Dropbox Folder Without Access Token

Tags: python, git, dropbox

I'm writing a set of examples for a gitlab repository that require a few image stacks that are around 200MB each. In total, it would be about 1GB of data for all the examples. Instead of including these in the git repository and taking up space there, I put the files into a public Dropbox repository with the thought of writing a wrapper function to auto-download the data if the user wants to run the example.

I have a few questions. First, is this a dumb way to go about the example data? Second, if it's not, then could I use the Dropbox Python API to access the publicly shared folder without requiring an access token? If that's not possible, would it be incorrect to make an access token and hard code it into access method?

Answer (score 1):

You should not hard-code an access token into your code and publish it to GitHub.

It is possible to access the contents of a Dropbox shared link without an access token. You can download from the shared link directly using the `dl` or `raw` parameter [as documented here](https://help.dropbox.com/share/force-download).

Example:

```
curl -L -o out.zip "https://www.dropbox.com/sh/abcdef123/gHijK?dl=1"
```

That would download the entire linked folder as a zip.

Note that this would consume [the Dropbox account's link bandwidth](https://help.dropbox.com/share/banned-links).

Comment: Awesome, thank you. If this reaches the link bandwidth limit, I'd be very surprised.